# How to effectively stationarise non-periodic wave signals?

Tags: python, time-series, filtering, signal-processing, wavelet

I am pre-processing a non-periodic signal for further implementation of autoregressive modelling on the signal. The signal is shown in the following figure. However, when I applied the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test to the signal with the threshold p-value = 0.01, the signal is tested as non-stationary. After implementing a first-order differencing or a differencing with a fixed interval on the non-stationary signals, the differenced signal is still tested as non-stationary. In this case, how do I effectively pre-process the raw signal so that the processed time series pass the ADF test(threshold p-value = 0.01)? Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: What is the nature of your signal? If you do not expect there to be a stationary component within a certain time frame, then transforming your signal until you find one is just getting the wrong answer. What is your signal source? I'm more familiar with traditional signal processing than wavelet signal processing, but maybe I can be of some help if given more info.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your actual signal may not be stationary (in any sense -- mean, variance, frequency, etc).

However, we can try to decompose your signal into a stationary component (if it exists) and a non-stationary component. I give an example below (there are many ways to do this from stats and signal processing literature -- I'm showing one way).

I created a small Python script to generate a signal somewhat like yours in that it has a strong periodicity with a "burst" amplitude in the middle (I also added in some actual noise on top of this).

For the analysis I'm using the `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL` filter (uses LOESS) to decompose the signal into trend, seasonality, and residual (it's an additive model -- Signal = Trend + Seasonality + Residual):

[image]

The ADF test gives a p-value of ~0.02 on the raw signal (top chart) and 0.0 when applied to the residual signal, so looks like we successfully separated the components.

Therefore, you can work with the residuals in any subsequent analyses and re-layer the trend and seasonality back in.

Hope this helps give you some ideas. There are many ways to do this.

Other approaches not demonstrated here include ARCH and GARCH process models that are mean to handle non-stationary volatility and volatility clustering:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity

---

python code

```py
from random import uniform

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import DecomposeResult, STL
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller


with open("signal.txt", 'r') as f:
    series = pd.Series(uniform(.5, 2)*float(i) for i in f.readlines())

adf = adfuller(series, store=True)
stat, pval = adf[:2]
print(f"Signal ADF Test: ADF={stat}, p-val={round(pval,2)}")

periods = []
p = 0
for i in range(len(series)-1):
    if series[i]*series[i+1] >= 0:
        p += 1
        continue
    periods.append(p)
    p = 0
T = round(sum(periods)/len(periods))
print(T)
result: DecomposeResult = STL(series, period=2*T).fit()
result.plot()
pyplot.show()

resid = result.resid

adf = adfuller(resid, store=True)
stat, pval = adf[:2]
print(f"Residual ADF Test: ADF={stat}, p-val={round(pval,2)}")
```